# LVM2 Recovery/Repair

Tags: linux, lvm, proxmox

Proxmox was running great with my LVM2 on my NVME storage until about an hour ago. I "think" it ran out of metadata storage because of the way that Proxmox configured the pool (which I didn't know until now). **The question is how to go about fixing it, or at least migrating the data to another drive.** I have looked up a bunch of stuff about repairing it, but nothing has worked.  (For reference it just isn't mounting the /dev/local-nvme.. )

Any help or suggestions? I have a spare drive I can move stuff to.

Below is the output of `pvdisplay`, `pvs`, `vgdisplay`, `vgs` and `lvs`

`PVDisplay`

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdf3
  VG Name               pve
  PV Size               237.97 GiB / not usable 1.32 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              60921
  Free PE               4094
  Allocated PE          56827
  PV UUID               

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1
  VG Name               local-nvme
  PV Size               238.47 GiB / not usable 2.34 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              61049
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          61049
  PV UUID
```

`PVS`

```
  PV           VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/nvme0n1 local-nvme lvm2 a--  238.47g     0
  /dev/sdf3    pve        lvm2 a--  237.97g 15.99g
```

`VGDisplay`

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               pve
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  32
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               237.97 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              60921
  Alloc PE / Size       56827 / 221.98 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       4094 / 15.99 GiB
  VG UUID               izaYTt-v1Oc-WohV-C2wd-wE9s-UECZ-fas1Tz

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               local-nvme
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  11
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                5
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               238.47 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              61049
  Alloc PE / Size       61049 / 238.47 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               N5aoAc-DxNy-8MW7-biAr-1H49-zz9i-be2qnI
```

`VGS`

```
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  local-nvme   1   5   0 wz--n- 238.47g     0
  pve          1   4   0 wz--n- 237.97g 15.99g
```

`LVS`

```
  LV               VG         Attr       LSize   Pool       Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  local-nvme       local-nvme twi---tz-- 238.24g
  local-nvme_meta0 local-nvme -wi------- 120.00m
  vm-100-disk-0    local-nvme Vwi---tz--  32.00g local-nvme
  vm-101-disk-0    local-nvme Vwi---tz--  32.00g local-nvme
  vm-103-disk-0    local-nvme Vwi---tz--  32.00g local-nvme
  data             pve        twi-aotz-- 151.63g                   4.61   0.26
  root             pve        -wi-ao----  59.25g
  swap             pve        -wi-ao----   8.00g
  vm-102-disk-0    pve        Vwi-aotz--  32.00g data              21.82
```